# Change sort order with shortcuts in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

How to change sort order with shortcuts? I know that I can put that in `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` file but what exactly to type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, of course you can put your preferred shortcuts in `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` to override the default in `/etc`. don't forget to put the section. e.g `[main]` , `[panel]`.

if you want to change the default keymap, but you don't know what to type, you can always refer the format in `/etc/mc/mc.default.keymap`

this is mine

```
[panel]
Sort = alt-!
SortPrev =
SortNext =
SortReverse = alt-@
SortByName = alt-#
SortByExt = alt+$
SortBySize = alt-%
SortByMTime =  alt-^
```

according to [Use a hotkey to toggle between two preferred sort orders](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2720) and [sort hotkey](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2698)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work with `alt-·`, [a middle dot (U+00B7)](https://unicode-table.com/en/00B7/) which is over 3 on es/Spanish layout (`localectl | grep 'X11 Layout'`).